# Running Geoserver in AWS Elastik Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, geoserver

I am currently running my web application using AWS services. In my app I use Geoserver but I could not find any way to run Geoserver with Elastik Beanstalk.
Geoserver runs with Tomcat which is Java and Beanstalk can run Java applications from what I know.

I managed to run Geoserver with Docker in EC2(t2-large) but I have paid lots of bills than I expected.

Answer (score 0):

Geoserver works in Elastic Beanstalk.  Create a java app and upload the geoserver.war file.  T2-small instance may be sufficient depending on your needs.